# Geometric intuition behind the second part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus

Is there any geometric intuition behind the second part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

The second part of the theorem is given as,

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(\mathrm{t})\mathrm{dt}=g(b) - g(a) $$

Where $g$ is the antiderivative of $f$.

Comment: $g$ describes the area under the curve $f$

Comment: It is indeed analytically evident. But how do we make it geometrically evident?

Comment: see [this page](http://www.intuitive-calculus.com/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus.html)

Comment: Look at the Riemann sum of the integral

Comment: @Dando18, in the second comment to Charlie's answer, I have tried to be more clear about what I am looking for. Also take a look at my first comment. I did express another doubt.

Comment: @R004 this is not necessarily geometric, but I've always intuitively understood it by thinking in terms of velocity ($v(t)$) and position ($s(t)$). We know $v(t)=s'(t)$ via definition and $\int_a^b v(t)dt$ is the displacement of the object on $[a,b]$ via dimensional analysis. We can also find the displacement of an object by finding the difference between two positions (i.e. $s(b)-s(a)$) so $\int_a^b v(t)dt = s(b)-s(a)$.  This is not a perfect argument, but it helped me first grasp the concept.

Comment: This is what I,  as a physics enthusiast, do to understand calculus better. For once, I wanted to not depend on the physical quantities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by geometric intuition, because they are many vaguely geometric ways of thinking about this.

One way that I linked intuitively the notion of area under the curve and the antiderivative of the function is this "geometric" intimate relation. Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

[image]

Imagine a function of the area under the function. For domain concerns, let's just assume this function measure the area under the curve from the start of the domain (or support) to the value in that function. Intuitively, let's show that this is really just the antiderivative with some constant difference (the $+C$ we get in differentiation).

In the picture above, the rectangles are wider and it forms a more approximate version of the actual area. But notice that when we take the LIMIT of the width of the rectangles to be infinitesimally small (width of $dx$) this area that we add on really is just the value $f(x)dx$ where $f$ is the original function, not the area function. Let A(x) be the area function previously described. The rate of change of this function, $\frac{dA}{dx}$, is exactly just the value of $f(x)$!! Therefore the rate of change of the area is the function itself, so $A(x)$ must be the antiderivative. Antiderivatives are all separated by a constant, so we subtract the start of the domain we are interested in to get that the area from $a$ to $a$ is 0 under the curve.

Another way of thinking about it (less rigorous) is just that the area is accumulating as you go along $x$, but the rate at which it accumulates is the function value itself as you add that little sliver to its area. Thus the rate of change is the function itself.

And the reason for why we subtract $g(a)$ is so that we may neglect the area from the beginning of the domain to $a$, as we are interested in the area and integral STARTING at $a$.

Hopefully this is the intuition you asked for.

Comment: I have, what might be a silly question in my head. Is the definition "The collection of all antiderivatives is called the indefinite integral" a starting point or are there mathematical reasons behind why they use the integral notion in the definition?

Comment: To be clear about my first question. Let's say $f(x)=x^2$. The collection of its primitives is, $g(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$. While computing the area under $f$ and $x$-axis as $x$ goes from bound $a$ to bound $b$, we take the difference of the primitives. I plot the graphs $f$ and $g$. From the graphs of $g$, how do I visualize their difference to be equal to the area under $f$. Am I unnecessarily looking for too much detail?

Comment: Indefinite integral is an analytical thing, and is just the antiderivative. This is because differentiation produces a new function and we want a way to invert this operation, which is the integral.

DEFINITE integrals are more of an evaluation thing, done numerically at a specified value. For any antiderivative you choose, (meaning for any $+C$ you choose) the value will be the same, which is why this notation is used. The constants will cancel each other out. If you are considering the area, the start (I used start of domain) is arbitrary. The difference is more important

Comment: This clears my understanding.

Comment: Good! I am glad to hear that. Hopefully you can select my answer